# Prove that sum almost surely diverges

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $X_1,...,X_i,...$ be a sequence of independent random variables so $EX_i=1/2$ and $X_i\in[-1,1]$ a.s. I would like to prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_=\infty$.

Note that I have no experience with probability theory. As a result, my approach will be to try and translate the problem into a purely analytic one following Folland's little table of equivalences between "probability-speak" and measure theoretic terms. This table can be found in his standard analysis text in the chapter on probability theory.

Now, I know I can treat the $X_i$ as measurable functions from the sample space to the reals I will call these functions $f_i$ instead of $X_i$ to make the notation more suggestive. That $EX_i=1/2$ implies that $\int f_idp=1/2$ with $p$ the probability. Since $X_i\in[-1,1]$ a.s., we can say that $p(\{x:|f(x)|>1\})=0$. In particular, we may as well just identify each $f_i$ with a function that is bounded entirely in this interval since measure zero sets don't contribute a whole lot. Now, what we want to prove is that the sum in question, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}f_i(x)$ diverges almost everywhere. This will show almost sure divergence as per Folland's little table of equivalences.

From here however, I have no idea how to prove the result. Can someone walk me through this, and suggest some intuition?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers

Comment: If $S_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ then $E[S_n] =\frac12n$ and $\textrm{Var}(S_n) \le \frac34n$ and I think you can then use Chebyshev's inequality to say something like $\mathbb P(S_n \ge  \frac14 n) \ge 1- \frac{12}{n}$ (this is a loose bound but good enough here) demonstrating divergence of $S_n$ to $+\infty$ since $\frac 14n \to +\infty$ and $1- \frac{12}{n} \to 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove even strong convergence (a.s.) to the infinity.

Let $Y_n=X_n-1/2 \in [-3/2,1/2]$; then $\mathbb{E} Y_n=0$ and $Y_n$'s are independent. Let $T_n=Y_1+\dots+Y_n$.

Observe that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} T_n^4&=\sum_{k} \mathbb{E}Y_k^4+4\sum_{k< l}\mathbb{E}[Y_k^3 Y_l]+6\sum_{k,l}\mathbb{E}[Y_k^2 Y_l^2]+12\sum_{k,l,m}\mathbb{E}[Y_k^2 Y_l Y_m]+24\sum_{k,l,m,r}\mathbb{E}[Y_k Y_l Y_m Y_r]
\\
&=\sum_{k} \mathbb{E}Y_k^4+6\sum_{k<l}\mathbb{E}[Y_k^2] \mathbb{E}[Y_l^2] 
\le C n^2
\end{align}
for some $C>0$ from indepence of $Y_k$'s and their boundedness. Hence by Markov's inequality
$$
\mathbb{P}(|T_n|\ge n\epsilon)\le \frac{\mathbb{E}[T_n^4]}{\epsilon^4 n^4}
\le\frac{C}{n^2\epsilon^4}
$$
and thus by Borel-Cantelli the event $\{|T_n|/n\ge \epsilon\}$ occurs finitely often. This means that $T_n/n\to 0$ a.s. and hence the claimed result about $\sum_i^n X_i\to \infty $ a.s. follows.